# Wie soll man ẞ (das große Eszett) schreiben?

Tags: handwriting, eszett

Mittlerweile ist das Eszett auch als Großbuchstabe in der deutschen Sprache offiziell anerkannt. Wie man es *tippt*, weiß ich (zumindest funktioniert auf meinem Win10-Rechner der Shortcut Umsch+AltGr+ß). Aber wie *schreibt* man es eigentlich, also mit Stift und Papier?

Wenn ich mir z.B. http://www.typografie.info/3/topic/25217-das-handschriftliche-versal-eszett-ein-selbstversuch/ ansehe, so erkenne ich zwei Schwierigkeiten:

1. Es wird dem B zu ähnlich. Statt GROẞER lese ich dann GROBER. (Was in Kombination mit UNSINN ja beides möglich wäre.)
2. Es sieht vor allem bei den Varianten mit Unterlänge eher nach dem gewohnten kleinen ß aus. Das aber soll ja genau vermieden werden. Wer Versalschrift schreibt, auch mit der Hand, will nicht den Eindruck erwecken, er hätte da irgendwo einen Kleinbuchstaben reingemogelt. Es ist nach meinem Eindruck außerdem die Regel, dass man auch in handgeschriebener Druckschrift, trotz aller individuellen Varianten, einen Großbuchstaben von seinem kleinen Pendant unterscheiden kann. Warum sollte das für das ß anders sein, nachdem es nun in beiden Varianten anerkannt ist?

Gibt es dazu schon irgendwo offizielle Empfehlungen? Oder gibt es von den Anbietern von Handschrifterkennungssoftware Hinweise, wie man den Buchstaben schreiben soll, damit er als ẞ und nicht als ß oder B erkannt wird?

**Präzisierung**: Mir geht es nicht um die Diskussion des praktischen Bedarfs für ein handschriftliches ẞ und auch nicht um individuelle Tipps. Worauf ich mit meiner Frage hinaus will: in der Schule wird das Schreiben aller Buchstaben gelehrt, außerdem gibt es in manchen Bereichen [Normschriften](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normschrift) – und nun ist ein neuer Buchstabe hinzugekommen. Da muss es doch eine Aktualisierung von Unterlagen wie [dieser hier](https://meinlehrmittel.de/media/images/org/20200001-01.jpg) geben?

Comment: Wie eine 13 schreiben, aber die 1 in die 3 fließen lassen, würde ich empfehlen

Comment: Gibt es überhaupt eine handschriftlichen Verwendungwendungszweck des großen ß im Alltag? Ich kann mich nicht erinnern jemals ein Wort nur in Großbuchstaben per Hand geschrieben zu haben aber das könnte auch daran liegen, dass ich für handschriftliches nur Schreibschrift verwende...

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda In Formularen kommt es manchmal vor: Bitte in Großbuchstaben auffüllen.

Comment: @ikadfoanhnfda Preis- und Werbetafeln in Geschäften oder Überschriften auf Grußkarten werden auch gerne mal mit der Hand und in Versalien geschrieben.

Comment: Ad 2: Warum soll vermeiden werden, dass der Großbuchstabe dem kleinen ähnelt? Bei den Buchstaben C/c, K/k, O/o, P/p, S/s, U/u, V/v, W/w, X/x, Y/y und Z/z ist das ja auch kein Problem.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Diese Paare sind durch den Größenunterschied trotzdem leicht unterscheidbar. Und Unterscheidbarkeit halte ich für wichtig a) aus Prinzip ;-), b) damit das lesende Auge eindeutig einen Großbuchstaben erkennen kann und nicht etwa eine Art umgekehrtes CamelCase signalisiert, c) für eindeutige Stifteingabe auf Tablets u.ä. (exotischer Fall, aber nervig, wenn man es dann doch mal braucht und es nicht geht)

Comment: @Matthias: Wo gibt es denn Größenunterschiede zwischen den Buchstaben eines Wortes, das in Versalschrift gesetzt ist? Bitte nenne Beispiele! (Denn wo sonst wird das große ẞ verwendet?)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich meinte, ein kleines x lässt sich schon anhand seines Höhen-Breiten-Verhältnisses, spätestens aber beim Vergleich mit anderen Buchstaben leicht von einem großen X unterscheiden. Ähnliches erwarte ich für ß und ẞ. Im übrigen war Punkt 2 in meiner Frage vor allem auf die Versuche mit Unterlänge gemünzt, z.B. die 2. und 6. Zeile des ersten Blattes auf der verlinkten Seite. Für die Varianten ohne Unterlänge gilt eher Punkt 1.

Comment: Ich bezweifle jetzt einfach mal, dass irgendwelche Kinder in irgendwelchen Schulen das "große ß" lernen.

Answer (score 7):

Der Grund für die Einführung des großen ẞ war eher typographisch
als orthographisch: Die bisherige Regelung ließ es zu, um
Mißverständnisse zu vermeiden, ein kleines ß inmitten von
Großbuchstaben zu verwenden (MAßE statt MASSE).
In den
meisten Fonts sieht das aber nicht gut aus: Das ß sticht aus
verschiedenen Gründen heraus; es ist manchmal höher als die
Großbuchstaben, meist schmaler, manchmal hat es auch noch eine
Unterlänge.
Gewünscht war darum ein Ersatz für das kleine ß, der sich an dieser
Stelle optisch besser einfügt, und
nicht unbedingt ein Zeichen, das deutlich anders aussieht
als das kleine ß.

Für die Handschrift sind diese Aspekte eher unwichtig.
Stattdessen kommt es aber darauf an, daß sich das große
ẞ sowohl von B als auch von R deutlich unterscheidet. Eine
Möglichkeit, das zu bewerkstelligen, heißt Unterlänge.
Dann sieht das große ẞ im wesentlichen wie das kleine ß aus,
aber die Unterscheidbarkeit von großem ẞ und kleinem ß ist,
beispielsweise in Formularen, meist nicht
von Belang.
Wenn man auf die Unterlänge verzichtet, dann hat man das Problem,
daß der Bogen rechts unten einerseits deutlich nach innen gehen
muß (sonst sieht's wie ein R aus), aber andererseits großen
Abstand zur Vertikalen links halten muß (sonst sieht's wie ein B aus).
Beides zusammen geht aber nur dann, wenn man das große ẞ
einigermaßen breit macht, also etwa wie [hier](http://www.typografie.info/3/topic/25217-das-handschriftliche-versal-eszett-ein-selbstversuch/),
Seite 3, Zeile 1, Nummer 4 bis 8.

Comment: Wenn man ausschließlich Großbuchstaben verwendet, hat man die Priorität der leichten Erkennbarkeit ohnehin aufgegeben, weil ja alle Buchstaben gleich hoch sind. Deswegen wird es gerne in Verträgen als Kleingedrucktes (kleiner Font) verwendet; damit man es schlecht lesen kann. Die Ergonomie jetzt an einem seltenen Buchstaben retten zu wollen ist vergebliche Liebesmüh.

Comment: Maschinenlesbare Formulare (z.B. Überweisungen), die Großbuchstaben erwarten, haben keinen Platz für Unterlängen. Ein kleines ß ohne Unterlänge aber gerät leicht zum B. Wie füllt man eine Überweisung an Max Groß aus, ohne dass Max Grob daraus wird und ohne auf Max Gross auszuweichen? (Unterstützung der Banksoftware für ẞ zumindest zukünftig mal vorausgesetzt.) - Der Hauptgrund für die Neuerung war im übrigen laut [Pressemitteilung](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_PM_2017-06-29_Aktualisierung_Regelwerk.pdf) die genaue Wiedergabe von Eigennamen in Pässen und ähnlichen Dokumenten.

Comment: @Matthias Dann halt breit. Die Beispiele [hier](http://www.typografie.info/3/topic/25217-das-handschriftliche-versal-eszett-ein-selbstversuch/), Seite 3, Zeile 1, Nr. 4 bis 8 sollten ziemlich eindeutig sein.

Answer (score 4):

Die gewöhnlichen Grossbuchstaben unterscheiden sich von den Kleinbuchstaben, sei es durch Form oder durch Grösse. Dies ist aber nicht Selbstzweck oder Prinzipienreiterei, sondern es hat praktische Gründe, etwa die folgenden:

### 1. Grund: Grossschreibung am Wortanfang

Am Wortanfang ist die Unterscheidung zwischen Gross- und Kleinbuchstabe bedeutungsvoll, so dass unterschiedliche Formen vorhanden sein müssen. Dies ist der eigentliche Hauptgrund für die unterschiedlichen Formen. Beim *ß* entfällt dieser Grund, denn es tritt nie am Wortanfang vor.

### 2. Grund: Aufzählungszeichen

Unter Umständen können Gross- und Kleinbuchstaben als separate Reihen von Aufzählungzeichen verwendet werden, so dass unterschiedliche Formen vorhanden sein müssen. Beim *ß* entfällt dieser Grund, denn es hat keine Stelle im Alphabet (so wäre etwa unklar, ob es denn nach S oder nach Z eingeordnet werden sollte).

### 3. Grund: Versalsatz

In Druckschriften sind die Grossbuchstaben ebenso wie die Kleinbuchstaben typographisch exakt aufeinander abgestimmt, so dass unterschiedliche Formen vorhanden sein müssen. Augenfällig wird dies im Versal- und im Kapitälchensatz, wo in einer Druckschrift ein kleines *ß* unschön hervorsticht. Aus diesem speziellen Grund ist das grosse *ẞ* geschaffen worden – und nicht aus den allgemeineren Gründen 1 und 2. In Handschriften entfällt dieser Grund. Im Gegensatz zu den Druckschriften sind sie nicht typographisch exakt gestaltet, so dass in einer Hanschrift das *ß* aus einer Reihe von Grossbuchstaben sowieso nicht hervorsticht (Kapitälchen sind in gewöhnlicher Handschrift unwahrscheinlich). Man braucht also von Hand das *ß* zwischen Grossbuchstaben nicht anders zu schreiben als sonst. Bei einer allfälligen Übertragung von Handschrift in Druckschrift wird aus dem Kontext eindeutig ersichtlich, dass ein grosses *ẞ* gemeint sein muss.

### 4. Grund: Verweis auf sich selber

Manchmal verwendet man einen bestimmten Buchstaben, um auf diesen Buchstaben selber zu verweisen, gewissermassen wie mit einem Eigennamen. Die speziellen Charaktere *ß* und *ẞ* ermöglichen dies in Druckschriften. In den allermeisten Fällen düften es Leute mit vertieften typographischen Kenntnissen sein, die diese Unterscheidung überhaupt treffen wollen. Diese Leute werden oft über die erforderliche kalligraphische Begabung verfügen, um ein kleines *ß* und ein grosses *ẞ* auch von Hand unterschiedlich zu zeichnen. Der naheliegende Behelf ist derselbe, der auch in der gesprochenen Sprache verwendet wird, nämlich die ausdrückliche Rede vom «grossen *ß».* Für einen klareren Stil und grössere Verständlichkeit ist dies in jedem Fall vorzuziehen.

### 5. Grund: Handschrifterkennung

Geräte mit Handschrifterkennung unterscheiden aus den Gründen 1 bis 4 die Eingabe von Gross- oder Kleinbuchstaben. Aus den Gründen 3 oder 4 kann es vorkommen, dass jemand an einem solchen Gerät ein explizites grosses *ẞ* eingeben will. In Zukunft dürften derartige Geräte das *ß* zwischen Grossbuchstaben automatisch wie ein *ẞ* darstellen. Technisch gesehen ist das Erkennen von Versalsatz ein relativ leichtes Problem. Grund 3 würde bei der Handschrifterkennung also entfallen, und es bliebe nur noch Grund 4 für Leute mit vertieften typographischen Kenntnissen – die denn oft auch alternative Eingabemöglichkeiten kennen werden.

### 6. Grund: CamelCase

Im CamelCase macht man sich Grund 1 in spielerischer Weise zur typographischen Gestaltung zu Nutze. Als ungewöhnliche Abwandlung davon kann auch ein umgekehrter cAMELcASE verwendet werden. Fürs *ß* wird CamelCase kaum zur Anwendung kommen. Der im Wortinnern hervorgehobene Buchstabe geht normalerweise auf einen Wortanfang zurück, aber das *ß* kann eben nie am Wortanfang stehen. Ausserdem würde man den umgekehrten cAMELcASE beim *ß* tunlichst vermeiden wollen, denn dadurch entstünde ja eben gerade der Eindruck, man hätte das *ß* falsch verwendet. Wenn man es trotzdem tun will – etwa in ironischer Absicht –, dann ist man sozusagen wieder bei Grund 4, wo man einen Buchstaben zum expliziten Verweis auf sich selber verwendet.

### Fazit

Es besteht also kein Handlungsbedarf, um die Vorlagen für die Handschrift zu aktualisieren. Die Gründe 1 (Grossschreibung am Wortanfang) und 2 (Aufzählungszeichen) entfallen beim *ß* sowieso, und bei Grund 3 (Versalschrift) kann in einer Handschrift problemlos das kleine *ß* verwendet werden. Grund 4 (Verweis auf sich selber) ist etwas für Leute mit vertieften typographischen Kenntnissen, Grund 5 (Handschrifterkennung) ist ein Spezialfall, der zudem in Zukunft meist entfallen dürfte, und Grund 6 (CamelCase) ist beim *ß* extrem unwahrscheinlich. Der tatsächliche Nutzen einer neuen Form für ein handschriftliches grosses *ẞ* ist also unerheblich und rechtfertigt in keiner Art und Weise den Aufwand einer Umgestaltung von Lehrmitteln, Alphabettafeln, Schulschriften usw. usw.

Comment: Wer z.B. die [Hamburger Druckschrift](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Hamburger_Druckschrift_ab_2011.jpg/1200px-Hamburger_Druckschrift_ab_2011.jpg) gelernt hat, schreibt Großbuchstaben ohne Unterlängen. Ein kleines ß kann dann schon recht unschön hervorstechen. Formulare haben oft keinen Platz für Unterlängen. Ohne Unterlänge aber steigt die Verwechslungsgefahr zum B. Unterscheidbarkeit von ß und ẞ könnte z.B. wichtig sein bei elektronischen Notizbüchern mit Stifteingabe. Warum sollte man dort nicht gezielt ein ẞ eingeben können? (Exotischer Fall, aber trotzdem...)

Comment: @Matthias: Das große J hat doch auch eine Unterlänge (sogar in dieser Hamburger Druckschrift) – warum sollte dann das große ß keine haben?

Comment: Stimmt, hatte ich übersehen. Aber mei, dann nimm irgendeine der Druckschriften [auf dieser Seite](https://schulschriften.info/schulschriften.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Benötigt und verwendet wird das große ẞ ausschließlich in der Versalschrift, denn es gibt kein einziges Wort, in keiner Sprache der Welt, das mit einem ß oder ẞ beginnt. Mit Versalschrift ist gemeint, dass jeder Buchstabe groß geschrieben wird (nicht nur der erste Buchstabe), und nur in diesem Fall kommt man überhaupt erst in die Situation, ein großes ẞ schreiben zu müssen:

> kleingeschrieben
>   Großschrift
>   VERSALSCHRIFT

Damit ist eine Schreib- oder Laufschrift ohnehin ausgeschlossen, denn bei einer solchen Schrift setzt man gemäß der Definition des Begriffs den Stift am Anfang des ersten Buchstaben des Wortes auf das Papier, schreibt das ganze Wort in einem durchgehenden Zug, ohne Absetzen des Stiftes, und hebt den Stift erst wenn man das Ende des letztes Buchstaben geschrieben hat, wieder vom Papier. (Danach setzt man noch etwaige Punkte auf i, j und Umlaute.) (Ausnahmen sind nur die Querstriche bestimmter Großbuchstaben, z.B. bei F oder T.) In Schreibschrift besteht also jedes Wort (von den genannten Ausnahmen abgesehen) aus einer einzigen durchgehenden Linie.

Die Großbuchstaben jeder Schreibschrift sind aber immer Anfänge von solchen Wort-Linien. Ein verbundener Übergang von einem Buchstaben zu einem nachfolgenden Großbuchstaben ist in Schreibschrift niemals notwendig, daher wird so etwas such niemals geschrieben.

Wer also von Hand ein Wort in Versalschrift schreibt, kann daher ohnehin keine Schreibschrift verwenden und muss daher in Blockschrift schreiben. Blockschrift ist die handschriftliche Nachahmung von Druckschrift. Meist, aber nicht immer, ist damit sogar die ausschließliche Verwendung von Großbuchstaben, also Versalschrift gemeint.

Damit ist eine Frage schon mal geklärt, nämlich die nach Unterlängen:

Unterlängen bei Großbuchstaben kommen nur in der Schreibschrift vor (nämlich bei G, J und Y). In Druckschrift, und damit in Blockschrift, hat kein einziger Großbuchstabe eine Unterlänge. Daher sollte auch das große ẞ keine Unterlänge haben, und das ist auch tatsächlich in allen Computerschriften, die ich mir angesehen habe, und in denen es ein ẞ gibt, der Fall.

Wie die konkrete Glyphe aussieht, hängt natürlich im Fall von gedruckten Schriften von der Schriftart ab. Mir sind folgende Varianten bekannt:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Wie die Beispiele zeigen, gibt es auch bei anderen Buchstaben (z.B. beim G) unterschiedliche Versionen. Und wie beim G muss man sich auch beim großen ẞ für eine dieser Versionen entscheiden.

Aber etwas haben alle vier Versionen gemeinsam: Sie lassen sich alle schreiben, indem man links unten beginnt, und den Buchstaben dann in einem einzigen Zug aufs Papier malt. Dann setzte man den Stift ab, und widmet sich dem nächsten Buchstaben.

Comment: Ich kenne die Handschrift mehrerer Personen, die ausschließlich nur Großbuchstaben schreiben... Dein *niemals* relativiert sich dadurch ein wenig.

Comment: Die [Hamburger Druckschrift](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Hamburger_Druckschrift_ab_2011.jpg/1200px-Hamburger_Druckschrift_ab_2011.jpg) wird in manchen Grundschulen verwendet und hat eine Unterlänge beim großen J (ich hab's auch erst mal übersehen). Ansonsten: vermutlich hat kaum einer von uns Großbuchstaben in Druckschrift dadurch gelernt, dass er sich verschiedene gedruckte Schriften angesehen und dann überlegt hat, wie er sie am besten mit dem Stift nachahmen könne. Das wurde vielmehr in der Schule gezeigt. Und nach Vorgaben/Beispielen dieser Art suche ich.

Comment: Takkat: Ich sprach auch nicht von »Handschrift« sondern von »Schreibschrift«. Das sind zwei verschiedene Dinge: Handschrift: Eine Schrift, die dadurch entsteht, dass man einen Stift mit der Hand über das Papier führt. Das kann durchaus auch Blockschrift sein. Schreibschrift: Eine (mehr oder weniger genormte) Schriftart, die ausdrücklich für die Verwendung als Handschrift vorgesehen ist. Ich selbst verwende als Handschrift z.B. keine Schreibschrift, sondern schreibe von Hand in Druckbuchstaben (jedoch nicht in Versalschrift).